# sum and group by in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq which returns values as shown below

[image]

I tried the below code to sum the associate points for team,

I wanted to get sum of associate points and team id

```
var result = from p in orderForBooks
group p by p.iTeamId into g
select new
{
    points = g.Sum(x => x.Associate_Points),
    teamid=g.Select(x=>x.iTeamId)
};
```

Its summing the associate points but the team id is not fetched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're grouping by `iTeamId`, you can simply get `iTeamId` for each group from group's `Key` :

```
var result = from p in orderForBooks
group p by p.iTeamId into g
select new
{
    points = g.Sum(x => x.Associate_Points),
    teamid = g.Key
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result   = orderForBooks
.GroupBy(t => t.iTeamId )
.Select(tm => new ResultObj
        {
            teamid= tm.Key,
            points = tm.Sum(c => c.Associate_Points)
        }).ToList();
```